# Local HTML form POST not working in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview

I have LOCAL HTML, which gets displayed in Webview, in which it has HTML form POST request.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
             <head>
             </head>
             <body>
                   <form name=“myForm"  method="post" action="https://test/mywebpage.aspx">
                        <input type="hidden" name=“filed1” value=“22”>
                        <input type="hidden" name=“filed”2 value=“testValue”>

                        <button type="submit">Send an HTTP POST request </button>
                   </form>

             </body>
       </html>
```

In this HTML, on button click, it send the POST request with some parameters to server. Using WKWebView, it doesn't send the parameters to server, because of that user get failure response.

Same HTML is able to get the valid response HTML using UIWebView as it successfully sent the parameter to server. But as UIWebView is deprecated in iOS we need to use the WKWebview.

Any solution for WKWebview?

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: Yes, I have extracted the request from html page and created URLsession request. In my case response of URLsession is html which I have loaded in web view and set the cookies too from URLsession to webview. now next POST request in webview is working, no need to create URLsession request